# jquery tab in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm facing a problem that I don't manage to solve by myself... That's why I need your help ;-)

My problem is when I add a jquery tab in the fluid part of an `fixed-left-list/fluid-detail` layout. The top of the tab is totally destroyed.

I found that when I clear the float of the detail div, the tab is back to normal. But actually that's not really what I want to do... :-(

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr63q/

What is your advice on my problem ?

Many thanks in advance!
Cedric.

Comment: its better if you put your code into http://jsfiddle.net/ its easier for people to help you and you to try figure it out :)

Comment: no problem, lets spread the good stuff right:)

Comment: How about this solution to your problem: set the float to parent container. http://jsfiddle.net/Mr63q/1/

Comment: But... in your example, the detail part is not anymore fluid layout ?! :-(

Comment: u right.. missed it :) lets see, what part should be fluid? as you have two containers(what element id?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr63q/3/

Comment: Yes! That's better... But is it possible to set the width of the tab 100% of the divDetail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discussed:
[CSS Layout: 2 column fixed-fluid (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516743/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid-again)

```
.ui-helper-clearfix {
    clear: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```